# Printing logs to STDOUT vs writing to file

Tags: linux, docker, unix, logging, log4j

I have an application that generates logs to a file, but it doesn't provide any log rotation strategy and fills up the disk quickly. *(Why so? I am still figuring it out)*

To mitigate this I have 3 options:

1. Add support for log rotation - *For some reason this would take a lot of time and would not prefer now*
2. use Linux logrotate - I can use this and this will rotate and purge log files
3. Simply publish the logs to /dev/stdout instead of to a file - *In my assumption this is not gonna take any disk space and will do my job*

If we skip point 2nd for time being, I am trying to understand the cons of writing logs to stdout instead of to a file.

**Few more info:**

- number of logs published per sec is a couple of thousands
- The log published to file or stdout will be shipped by a separate process to ELK/logstash

I know the best and simple approach would be to support log rotation/purging within the application, however, can someone kindly help me understand the pros and cons of using stdout vs file for logging.

I am relatively new to this concept, any help or pointer to the right document would be really helpful.

Comment: You don't need to implement log rotation, your logging framework most certainly already has this feature. Or are you "logging" through `System.out`?

Comment: You tagged this as "docker"; in a container context you should almost always log to stdout and not a file.  This lets tools like `docker logs` work and you can point the external log collector at the container system.

Comment: ("Thousands of logs per second" is a lot IME and you might consider whether to turn down the logging level to improve the signal-to-noise ratio in your logs.)

Comment: @DavidMaze: log appenders that use `System.out` in Java are painfully slow (cf. [this benchmark](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/cloud.html)). That is why logging to a file is more current.

Comment: ...so it's still blazingly fast compared to your database I/O, and essentially free if you can reduce the log level to, say, at most tens of log messages per second.

Comment: _Why_ are you looking to STDOUT as a destination for logs?  STDERR was invented for this purpose 50 years ago!

Answer (score 0):

If you already use centralized logging via ELK/logstash and disk space of the log server is no problem, then there is no reason to save it to local disk. So I see no problem in just printing it to stdout (via a console appender, not System.out directly) since you don't lose the logs if it is published to ELK.

Additionally if you run the application in docker/container then docker saves a copy of the last X lines and uses its own mechanism to not fill up the disk

Are there more restrictions/condtions why you should have local copy of the log?
If no => just print to stdout
If yes => not generally answerable

Does the seperate process only run every X min/secs and you can't miss a single line of log?
=>  Then save a local copy and keep the sync ratio small and try to split the log in files according to ration for easy deletion of older log files that already synced (if mechanisms like log rotation are not already implemented in the logging framework, but "sperate process" sounds like something "selfmade" process for log collection and publishing)

Or is it published to ELK instantly via a "log appender"?
=> Just print it to stdout (via console appender)